# In Eclipse, how to set JavaDoc URL on a classpath entry programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, javadoc, eclipse-jdt

I have an Eclipse plugin, that among other things, can create a project and give it several classpath entries.  This in and of itself works fine.

These jars do not have source included in the, however there is a URL that can be used for Javadoc.  I want to set this up programmatically for these classpath entries that the plug-in creates.  This is what I'm doing:

```
  IClasspathEntry cpEntry;

  File[] jarFile = installFilePath.listFiles();

  IPath jarFilePath;
  for (int fileCount = 0; fileCount < jarFile.length; fileCount++)
  {
      jarFilePath = new Path(jarFile[fileCount].getAbsolutePath());
      cpEntry = JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(jarFilePath, null, null);
      entries.add(cpEntry);
  }
```

I could not figure out how to set the JavaDoc URL location on a claspath entry.  This can be done in the Eclipse UI - for instance, if you right-click the project, go to Properties... -> Java Build Path, and expand one of the JAR entries and edit the "Javadoc Location", you can specify a URL.  How do I do this from within a plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
        Path   pth = new Path( MY_JARFILE_LOCATION );
        Path   pthd = new Path( MY_JAVADOC_LOCATION );
        ClasspathAttribute att = new ClasspathAttribute("javadoc_location", "file:" + pthd.toOSString());
        IClasspathAttribute[] atts = new IClasspathAttribute[] { att };
        IClasspathEntry cpISDI = JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(pth, null, null, null, atts, false);
        cpEntries.add(1, cpISDI);
```

(edited formatting)

Answer (score 1):

yakir's answer is correct, but it's better to use the public factory method `JavaCore.newClasspathAttribute()` rather than directly constructing `ClasspathAttribute` (which is Eclipse private API). For example:

```
File javadocDir = new File("/your/path/to/javadoc");
IClasspathAttribute atts[] = new IClasspathAttribute[] {
    JavaCore.newClasspathAttribute("javadoc_location", javadocDir.toURI().toString()),
};
IClasspathEntry cpEntry = JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(libraryPath, null, null, null, atts, false);
```

Comment: You can also replace

`JavaCore.newClasspathAttribute("javadoc_location", ...`


with


`JavaCore.newClasspathAttribute(IClasspathAttribute.JAVADOC_LOCATION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ...`