# How to programmatically specify JRE javadoc location in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-jdt

You can manually set it via

_Package Explorer / JRE System Library / rt.jar -> contextmenu -> properties
- Attach Javadoc..

And the settings are stored in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.launching.prefs.

I wonder is there anyway I can programmatically specify it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: a bit duplicated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015244/in-eclipse-how-to-set-javadoc-url-on-a-classpath-entry-programmatically, also without answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc is [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/launching/package-summary.html).

The method you want is IVMInstall#setJavadocLocation(URL).  You need to create a VMStandin from the existing IVMInstall, modify its javadoc location, then do VMStandin#convertToRealVM() which will apply the changes.

JavaRuntime has a few methods for getting IVMInstalls.